# Spring integration - managing the TCP connection

Tags: java, spring

I've been looking at using Spring integration to manage connecting via TCP to a remote service and have a few questions...

I need to re-use the same connection for the duration of the communication until I know the sequence of messages have been completed. Is there a way to do this out of the box?

E.g. a Client sends a message with txnId: 12345. Any subsequent messages from that client with the same txnId needs to use the same connection, until the final message is sent, at which point I would need to close the connection to the remote server.

I've had a bit of a play around and it looks like I would have to manually manage the connections to some extent?

Comment: Can two different `txnIds` use the same connection or would one `txnId` effectively block a connection until the final message is sent?

Comment: One txnId would effectively block the connection until the final message is sent - i.e. I cannot re-use the connection for messages for a different txnId.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you only need a List to store all sockets. config the list in the spring, and then inject the list to any object which need go through all sockets.